# Facebook: link from app activity leads to URL and not to the app

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps, facebook-canvas

I'm building a little app for math exercises. I've an URL (leads to index.php) for the canvas view. When I select a topic in this canvas view, it calls another URL (domain.com/exercise/id) that is loaded in the canvas view.

All my id's are tagged with open graph meta-informations for OG aggregation.

So far so good. But the URL of my 'items' is on my domain - the domain that will be shown in the iframe in canvas view.

I post an activity like this:

```
FB.api('/me/mymathapp:solve' +
    '?exercise_serie=' + exeSerieUrl + '?access=' + accessToken,'post',
    function(response) {});
```

But now the link to my exercise in the activity feed on my wall leads to my website and not to the canvas-page of my app. Altought I only setup my canvas URLs - nothing else.

Are there any settings, that those URLs should only show up in canvas view? Or do I've to do a workaround like redirect to the canvas view form my page?

Thanks in advance,
Jurik

Answer (score 1):

I believe in this case you need to redirect back to your canvas app if the user lands on the URL for the Object (obviously, with an exception in your redirect code for Facebook's crawler)

The existing Open Graph apps like Spotify use this method, a link to an example song object is: http://open.spotify.com/track/737liXlwQnrGkVszJqVbOv which will open Spotify if you have the app, and links to their site if you don't

Comment: Interessting - because I got my app and it doesn't open my app, but links me to my site. So Spotify does something different then me - because my link almost looks like the one from Spotify. http://mydomain.com/exercise/<id of exercise>

Comment: Spotify may be special cased because they're using built-in actions which Facebook handles separately, but in general i think the stories link to the URL of the action or object and not necessarily to the app's canvas or website URL